# Does There Exist A Fourth Independent Axiom Here?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, metalogic

I use [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

The implicational calculus of propositions under detachment and uniform substitution has the following axioms as a basis:

```
1 CpCqp
2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
3 CCCpqpp
```

If one joins to this system say

```
4 CCNpNqCqp or 
5 CCNpNqCCNpqp
```

one obtains a basis for all C-N tautologies (conditional-negation tautologies... that is all tautologies which only have "C" and "N" connectives can get obtained from such an axiom set).  But, if we do such, then the axioms are no longer independent, since both {1, 2, 5} and {1, 2, 4} allow us to deduce CCCpqpp.  So, does there exist an axiom which we can join to the above three axioms... the set {1, 2, 3} ... for a basis for C-N calculus which keeps all of the axioms independent?

Comment: I suppose that **(A3)** of Mendelson : $(\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p) \rightarrow ((\lnot q \rightarrow p) \rightarrow q)$ must replace Peirce's law.

Comment: A3 of Mendelson is the 5th formula I mentioned (up to renaming of variables).

Comment: Sorry; what it is not clear to me, is why you want to *add* it; if you replace your 3 with 5, you will have a three axioms system (all independent) which is complete for implication and negation.

Comment: how about adding CNpCpq and CCpqCCpNqNp(the intuitionistic negations axioms) or other non classical negations axioms (CCpqCNqNp for example) then CCCpqpp stays independend

Comment: @Willemien If you only add CCpqCNqNp to {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCCpqpp}, then CCNpNqCqp is still not derivable.  If you add CNpCpq and CCpqCCpNqNp, then you've added two axioms, but yes you can prove all tautologies (though I'm not sure at this point that such a 5 axiom set would have independent axioms).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It just seems interesting to do things that way.  Thinking more on it I, part of my interest could get solved by referring to the axiom set {CCCpqrCCrpCsp, CCNpNqCCNpqq} for C-N classical logic which has independent axioms and also has a subset of axioms... namely {CCCpqrCCrpCsp}... which allows us to derive all implicational tautologies.  Still, it seems somewhat interesting to try and find a fourth axiom here where upon joining it independence gets preserved.

Comment: @Willemien But, CNpCpq and CCpqCCpNqNp could get "packed up into a single formula" using methods similar to how a set of axioms can get packed up into a single axiom.  Independence might still hold then, but we'll need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to be no, by the following reasoning.

Assume you had such an axiom.
You could then get all of the C-N tautologies.
4 and 5 are such tautologies, so you could get them.
And you've already stated that having them makes 3 redundant.

So, in general, anything that adds all the C-N tautologies makes 3 redundant.

Comment: Interesting idea, and I thought it correct at first.  If, we add some axiom x to {1, 2, 3}, then yes we can get 3, 4, and 5 from {1, 2, 3, x}.  But, it doesn't follow that from {1, 2, x} we can get 3, nor that we can get 4 or 5.  So, 3 could still be independent.  The independence of x is more straightforward and works out by definition.

Comment: But the question doesn't ask Adding x to 1, 2.... It specifically asks adding it to those three.

Comment: @JohnHalleck I'm pretty sure Doug is right here. You write: "Assume you had such an axiom. You could then get all of the C-N tautologies." But that only makes number 3 redundant if number 3 is not one of the axioms that you use to get number 4 and number 5. Your argument only works if, from {1, 2, x}, we can get 4 and 5 (and thus 3).

Comment: Yes, it doesn't.  But, if 3 is redundant then it follows that {1, 2, x} will allow us to derive 3.  I'll go back to your argument.  We assume that we had such an axiom.  We can get all of the C-N tautologies from {1, 2, 3, x}.  4 and 5 are such tautologies, so you could get them.  And from what I said above, since both {1, 2, 4} and {1, 2, 5} that that makes 3 redundant.  But, the scope is now {1, 2, 3, x}, not {1, 2, x}.  The question concerns whether or not {1, 2, x} can derive 3 if {1, 2, 3, x} is strong enough to derive all C-N tautologies.

Comment: @TannerSwett Even though I don't think John's argument works, I think his intuition is that no such axiom exists.  I'm inclined to believe that such an axiom exists.

Comment: @Tanner;   Four and five are stated to be" joined onto the system".  Therefore they are clearly intended to be additions to the system.